# On the Picard group of the generic fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a flat morphism of factorial projective varieties and denote by $X_{\eta}$ the generic fiber of $f$. Does the inequality
$$\rho(X)\leq \rho(X_{\eta}) + \rho(Y)$$
among the Picard numbers hold?

Here is a potential argument: consider the exact sequence
$$Pic(Y)\rightarrow Pic(X)\rightarrow Pic(X_{\eta})\rightarrow 0$$
and let $K$ be the kernel of the first map. Then we have an exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow K\rightarrow Pic(Y)\rightarrow Pic(X)\rightarrow Pic(X_{\eta})\rightarrow 0$$
So $\rho(X)+\dim(K) = \rho(X_{\eta}) + \rho(Y)$.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, here is a counter example. Elliptic fibrations are flat, this is a consequence of the so called "miracle flatness theorem".

Consider an Enriques surface $X$, (quotient of K3 surface by $\mathbb{Z}_2$), every such surface admits an elliptic fibration $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. By Bombieri-Mumford every Enriquez surface has picard rank $10$, and since the base has picard rank $1$ and a generic fibre (= smooth elliptic curve) has picard rank $1$, we get a contradiction with the inequality.

Comment: Thank you. In this case are there many divisors in $X$ that are contracted by $f$ but that are not pull-backs of divisors on $\mathbb{P}^1$ via $f$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, The contribution will come from fibres which are not reducible. If $f^{-1}(p) = [c_1] + [c_{2}] + \ldots [c_k]$ for $k>1$, then the classes $[c_{k}]$ will not be the pull back of a divisor on $\mathbb{P}^1$, there will be a rank $k-1$ subgroup of the Neron-Severi group which intersects the image of $f^*$ only at $0$.

Comment: Is it enough to assume that all the fibers of $f:X\rightarrow Y$ are irreducible to avoid this kind to things?

Comment: Yes, that looks to be correct; at least for surfaces (I haven't checked it formally though)